# this program is compiling perfectly but at runtime a problem with a class which is imported

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am using *light weight bouncy castle package* and this is my code

```
X9ECParameters x9=NISTNamedCurves.getByName("p-224");
ECDomainParameters params=new ECDomainParameters(x9.getCurve(),x9.getG(),x9.getN(),x9.getH());
ECKeyGenerationParameters gp=new ECKeyGeneratorParameters(params,SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));
......
```

This program compiles successfully but generates run time error ..

```
java.lang.NOClassDefFoundError:java/security/SecureRandom
```

....

How can i solve it?

Comment: do you have `jar` file containing `SecureRandom` class in your path when you are running it?

Comment: yup. i have imported the required classes for SecureRandom. But i dont know why i am getting this error

Comment: @Gabe: People should learn *how to ask questions*. ;-)

Comment: @user609282: I'm not asking that you have imported the class or not I'm asking whether you have added jar file in your build/run path or not?

Comment: @Harry: that class is part of the standard API and should not require adding any JAR.

Comment: @Michael: if thats the thing then as you said in your answer he must be developing in tech other than JAVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should be using the J2ME version of the BC package. It includes it's own version of `java.security.SecureRandom` as well as other needed classes that are not in the J2ME. It is right there on the [latest releases](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) page, just search for lcrypto-j2me to find it on the page.

Comment: we are using the lcrypto j2me version only but there is a problem with only SecureRandom class file ...when i am trying to obtain the .java file from the class file netbeans is giving a different file than what actually provides in the package.?

Answer (score 2):

`SecureRandom` has been part of the Java standard API since Java 1.1, so what are you trying to run the code on? Google App Engine? Android? Java ME? Those are all environments that don't support the full Java Standard API library.

You'll have to investigate whether your platform offers a different source of high-quality randomness.

Comment: i am using this in j2me and i have added the jar file. without adding the jar file it will not even compile